# Decorating 1 of multiple implemented interfaces

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, decorator

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a decorator for 1 of multiple implemented interfaces in C#. I'm leaning towards no, but maybe.

Here's what I mean

```
public abstract class Auditable
{
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : Auditable
{
  // <...> properties
}


public interface IWriteRepository<T> : where T : Auditable
{
    T Create(T entity);
    T Update(T entity);
}

public class AuditRepositoryDecorator<T> : IWriteRepository<T> where T : Auditable
{
    private readonly IWriteRepository<T> _decorated;

    // <...> ctor with injects

    public T Create(T entity)
    {
        entity.ModifiedAt = time;
        entity.CreatedAt = time;
        entity.CreatedBy = invoker;
        entity.ModifiedBy = invoker;

        return _decorated.Create(entity);
    }

    public T Update(T entity)
    {
        entity.ModifiedAt = time;
        entity.ModifiedBy = invoker;

        return _decorated.Update(entity);
    }
}


public interface IMyClassRepository : IWriteRepository<MyClass>
{
     MyClass Get(int id);
}
```

So I would like to be able to depend on `IMyClassRepository` repository and whenever `Create` or `Update` would get invoked it would go through `AuditRepositoryDecorator`. It's a piece of logic that is executed a lot and I think it would be much simpler to have as a decorator instead of having a composition relation to some interface that does the same.

`IAuditableRepository` is never instantiated directly, as it's would always be implemented by another interface, so I think it might not be possible to do what I want to achieve.

I'm using the default dnc2.1 DI framework with [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) for decorations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. This isn't a limitation of the used DI Container, but rather a constraint of the .NET Type system. I often advise developers that are in DI trouble to, for the sake of understanding, remove the DI Container from the equation and instead build object graphs by hand. This works well in your situation, as I'll demonstrate below.

Assume you have an `IMyClassRepository` consumer:

```cs
public class RepoConsumer
{
    RepoConsumer(IMyClassRepository repo) ...
}
```

And an `IMyClassRepository` implementation:

```cs
public class MyClassRepositoryImpl : IMyClassRepository
{
    ...
}
```

Now let's create the object graph for `RepoConsumer` that uses `AuditRepositoryDecorator<MyClass>`:

```cs
var repo = new MyClassRepositoryImpl();
var decoratedRepo = new AuditRepositoryDecorator<MyClass>(repo);
var consumer = new RepoConsumer(decoratedRepo); // <-- COMPILE ERROR
```

When you compile this code, you'll notice that the C# compiler will generate an error on the `new RepoConsumer` line. This is because `RepoConsumer` expects an `IMyClassRepository`. Although `MyClassRepositoryImpl` implements `IMyClassRepository`, `AuditRepositoryDecorator<MyClass>` **does not** implement `IMyClassRepository`.

To solve this, you might try letting `AuditRepositoryDecorator<T>` implement `IMyClassRepository`, but that will obviously be ugly, because the decorator will have to implement a dozen of interfaces, for each entity in your system.

But what this exercise proves, is that the problem is not so much with the DI Container, but rather that the type system simply not permits you to build an object graph of this. And since the type system doesn't allow you to, the DI Container certainly won't allow it. It can't work around the type checks of the type system. Fortunately.

But the solution to your problem is actually *really* straightforward: remove the specific `IMyClassRepository` and let consumers depend on `IWriteRepository<MyClass>` instead. This might seem a disappointing solution, but there is a myriad of problems surrounding deriving from generic interfaces. Just accept the fact that consumers depend on such generic abstraction. It takes some time, but eventually, you will start to love and appreciate this style of programming.

But, of course, this still leaves us with the question of how to add new methods, such as `MyClass Get(string)`. There are multiple solutions, such as:

- Implement it as extension method (only possible when the method itself requires access to the interface itself, not to the class's internals)
- Define a separate interface, which might be a good idea in general, according to the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)

Answer (score 1):

the most used approach in these cases is the repository pattern as explained here in my answer: [How do I avoid code repetition when defining a class of functions that only vary the data type of the parameters they handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798825/how-do-i-avoid-code-repetition-when-defining-a-class-of-functions-that-only-vary/62804487#62804487)

in your case this is the classes hierarchy:

```
public interface IWriteRepository<T> : where T : Auditable
{
   T Create(T entity);
   T Update(T entity);
}

public abstract class WriteRepositoryBase<T> : IWriteRepository<T> where T : Auditable
{
    //implement create and update
}
public interface IMyRepository : IWriteRepository<MyClass>
{
     MyClass Get(string id);
}

public class MyRepository : WriteRepositoryBase<MyClass>, IMyRepository
{
     //implement Get
}
```